# How to choose multiple folders with the system file picker?

Tags: android

An intent like this:

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
```

allows to choose only one folder from the files.

Is it possible to create an intent allowing to choose multiple directories from the files ?

Comment: There is the action to pick content `Intent(ACTION_GET_CONTENT)` with extra `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)` but I've never seen it to be used with folders so far. But for files it works.

Comment: i need to choose multiple folders but `Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` doesn't allow it  :(

Comment: I've never seen something similar on Android to be honest... maybe you need a different approach and do it by selecting each folder at a time with an in app helper screen that display the picked up folders so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Is it possible to create an intent allowing to choose multiple directories

No. Not possible.